# import global scss variables with Vue CLI and Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vuetify.js

when importing a global scss file into my project via:

1. import into `main.js`, didn't let me use the variables i defined but classes and ids work.
2. import into `App.vue`, didn't load any styles at all. and i removed the `scoped` of course
3. import into `vue.config.js` as following

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "@/scss/_variables.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

breaks my whole application and gives me tons of errors in cmd rel. to Vuetify.

can anybody tell me how i can import a global scss into a SPA made with latest Vue CLI and Vuetify?

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to import the variables explicitly. According to the official documentation [https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#sass-variables) `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify` do this itself. To use global variables just follow these simple steps.

1. Add Vuetify using command `vue add vuetify` This will automatically add all the required dependency like `vuetify-loader, vue-cli-plugin-vuetify`, etc.
2. Make a `variables.scss` file in  `src/{scss, sass or styles}` directory. As these are the default directories for global variables [Example variable file](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#example-variable-file).
3. Run the server, you are ready to go.

Comment: this should marked as the correct answer. thank you @Amanjot Singh

Comment: @Deniz You should mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

In general, this seems to work now:

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                additionalData: '@import "~@/assets/scss/_variables.scss";'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works with @vue/cli 4.5.9

Comment: No, It doesn't work. You must write `scss`.